# Find the number of paired letter between two string

Tags: python

I have two files that should be read. Each line in files contains strings. I just try to find the number of paired character at the same position into the strings. For example my first file like this:

```
ADEFGHAS
WESDHYKLMANYTRB
SAEDLKIANJJHHV
...
```

And the second file:

```
ACDE
STRBGH
LKANBG
...
```

The program should work like this:

```
   ADEFGHAS     ADEFGHAS      ADEFGHAS    ADEFGHAS   ADEFGHAS
                               ||         |                          .....
ACDE          ACDE           ACDE         ACDE        ACDE
 hit=0           hit=0         hit=2      hit=1       hit=0
```

Max hit number/length(string2) (Here 2/4=0.5) should be output of these two string. It should make this for all strings in files. The output will be like this:

```
     str1    str2      str3  ...  --(lines of second file)
str1  0.5      0.2     0.0    ...
str2  0.6      1.0     0.3    ...
...   ...     ...      ...     ...
 |
(lines of first file)
```

I tried code below in python

```
def hitNumber(str1, str2):

   str1 = str1 
   str2= str2
 
   return sum(1 if i == j else 0 
           for i, j in zip(str1, str2)) / float(len(str2))


string1 = 'EAALEQ'
string2 = 'KYEI'

result = hitNumber(string1, string2)

print ("The hitNumber between 2 strings is : " + str(result))
```

but it starts from first point of both strings and does not consider of other steps.
How can I resolve this problem and calculate for the files correctly?

Comment: Please share your attempts! Take a look at [tour] and ask about providing a [mre]!

Comment: how it is `0.2` for `str1` and `str2`?? it should be `2/6` according to your logics. Am I right?

Comment: Also why it is `0.5` for `str1` and `str1`? Should not it be `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive solution

```
import pandas as pd  # only used for final formatting

def substrings(mother):
    " returns the list of sub strings of a string, ordered in reverse of their lengths "
    return [sub for sub_len in range(len(mother),0,-1)
                for sub in [mother[start: start + sub_len] for start in range(0, len(mother)- sub_len + 1)]
           ]

def best_ratio_sub_in(subs_list, string):
    " returns the best ratio for substrings 'subs_list' in 'string'  "
    lens = len(subs_list[0])
    for sub in subs_list:
        if sub in string:
            return len(sub)/lens
    return 0

def datavalues(searched_in, searched_for):
    """
    Builds a list of list of best_ratio
    For all strings(si) in searched_in, for all strings(sf) in searched_for, all substrings of sf are searched and the best ratio len(found substring)/len(df) is inserted in the table
    Parameters:
    searched_in: list of strings to be searched in
    searched_for: list of strings to be searched for

    Returns:
    a list of lists
    """
    bests = []
    for sf in searched_for:
        subslist = substrings(sf)
        bests.append([best_ratio_sub_in(subslist, si) for si in searched_in])
    return [list(tup) for tup in zip(*bests)] # transpose 'bests'

data = datavalues(strs1, strs2)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index = strs1, columns = strs2)
```

```
>>> df
                 ACDE    STRBGH    LKANBG
ADEFGHAS         0.50  0.333333  0.166667
WESDHYKLMANYTRB  0.25  0.500000  0.333333
SAEDLKIANJJHHV   0.25  0.166667  0.333333
```

Extended subs function to allow for matching patterns where a part in the form A[XYZ]B implies AXB or AYB or AZB, see in abcabc's comments below (Should also work for AB[XY]CD[VW]EF, but beware to the time complexity).

```
_subspattern = re.compile(r"([^\[]*)((\[[^\[]*\])(.*))*") # used in 'substrings' function

def substrings(mother):
    " returns the list of sub strings of a mother string, ordered in reverse of their lengths "
    
    def sorted_list_set(lst): # lst -> list of sorted on length set elements  
        return sorted(set(lst), key=lambda x: (-len(x), x))
    
    matches = re.search(_subspattern_re, mother)

    groups = matches.groups()
    prefix = groups[0] if groups[0] else ""
    toexpand = groups[2][1:-1] if groups[2] else ""
    leftover = groups[3] if groups[3] else ""

    if not toexpand: # if nothing to expand
        return sorted_list_set(sub for sub_len in range(len(mother),0,-1)
                for sub in [mother[start: start + sub_len] for start in range(0, len(mother) - sub_len + 1)]
               )
    
    childs = [prefix + c + leftover for c in toexpand]
    childs_subs = []
    for child in childs:
         childs_subs.extend(substrings(child)) #  recursive call for multiple expansion items
    
    return sorted_list_set(childs_subs)
```

Comment: I added these for reading files: "s1=open('firstFİle.txt','r')
s2=open('secondFile.txt','r')
strs1= s1.readline()
strs2=s2.readline() " but it did not work. What should I add for reading from files? Also thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @abcabc: Check strs1, strs2.  It works here with `with open('filestrs1.txt','r') as f: strs1=f.read().splitlines()` and the same for strs2

Comment: It worked. But the reason is that data = datavalues(strs2, strs1) should be data = datavalues(strs1, strs2) . Thank you again.

Comment: I clarified the use of datavalues parameters in its docstring

Comment: I just want to ask one more question. Can we apply this on strings in regular expression format. First file will be the same but the other file will be in regex format like AC[DE]. [DE] means it can be D or E but not both of them. And also when X appears in string, it means it can be any letter.

Comment: @abcabc:  1/ In `best_ratio_sub_in`, you could modify `if sub in string` by what you want 
    2/ but how could we define substrings of a regex as regex are matching patterns , not a generating rules ? 3a/ For your case, it would be necessary to define generative rules , possibly regex like, b/ Then the `subs`function should be modified in order to generate the set of possible sub_strings from a generating rule 4/ Even if the question of 'subtrings' was answered, how would the ratio be defined?

Comment: What you mean with ratio? For example for ABD[CE] the string length will be 5. Here, all regex represantation is not necessary. Just using of [ ] and X is important. Can be done something like this "if letter in string starts with [ and finish with ] one of letters between it should be included" etc.

Comment: @abcabc I put an upgraded function, at the end of the answer.

Comment: How can we integrate it into the first one? And Using X is wrong. As I mentioned it before X means it can be any letter except X in the string. Because our string includes aminoacid letters(A,R,N,D,C,Q,G,E,H,I,L,K,M,F,P,S,T,W,Y,V). X can be one of these letters. (Thank you so much for your help.)

Comment: @abcabc 1/ The code process letters, if there are no 'X' fine, if there are 'X' it wont  break it. 2/ Substitute the second code (with the re.compile line) to the `substrings` def of the first part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this function which traps all substring of str2, sort the list and find the maxhit:

```
def maxHit(str1, str2):
    res = [str2[i: j] for i in range(len(str2))
       for j in range(i + 1, len(str2) + 1)]

    sorted_list = list(sorted(res, key = len, reverse=True))

    for sb in sorted_list:
        if sb in str1:
            return len(sb) / len(str2)

    return 0.0

print(maxHit("qsthsqdsdsdsdsdsdsd", "python"))  # here 2/6 = 0.3333
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the others' solutions, but I'll post mine as well just because mine is the dumbest, and some might find this easy to understand.

```
def hitNumber(str1, str2):
    maximum = 0
    len_str2 = len(str2)
    for x in range(1, len(str1) + len_str2):
        v = sum(1 if i == j else 0 
           for i, j in zip(str1[max(x - len_str2, 0):], str2[-x:]))
        if v == len_str2:
            return 1
        if v > maximum:
            maximum = v
    return maximum / len_str2
```